# How to make point "adder" button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently working on a game/app which a criteria-based point game. I using the technologies, Ionic 3 with Angular which helps with the GUI and ease of testing and deployment.

**The issue I am having is :** I can't get my score variable to change (go up) when the add point button is clicked.

**What I have tried :** Declaring it as a variable in many different ways with no avail. I'm still new to HTML and JS so any help would be appreciated. It's still super work in progress!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@4.7.4/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
  <style>
    :root {
      --ion-safe-area-top: 20px;
      --ion-safe-area-bottom: 22px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>

    function openMenu() {
      document.querySelector('ion-menu-controller');
        .open();
    }

    function p1point(){
      var p1pp = document.getElementById("p1p")
      p1pp = p1pp + 1


    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-menu side="start">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar translucent>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="home" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="person" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="chatbubbles" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Messages</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="settings" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <div class="ion-page" main>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
          </ion-buttons>
          <ion-title>Point Game</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-card>
                <!--Player 1 score-->
                <ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-subtitle class = "ion-text-center">Player 1</ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-title class = "ion-text-center" id = "p1p">0</ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
              </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size = -1>
              <!-- fake inner thing psuedo-col-->

            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-card>
                <!--Player 2 score-->
                <ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-subtitle class = "ion-text-center">Player 2</ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-title class = "ion-text-center" ><var>0</var></ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
              </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-button id = "p1plus" onclick="p1point()"> + </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>

      </ion-content>
    </div>
  </ion-app>
  <ion-menu-controller></ion-menu-controller>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some Syntex errors:

```
function openMenu() {
      document.querySelector('ion-menu-controller').open(); 
    }

    function p1point(){
      var p1pp = document.getElementById("p1p").innerText; //getting text inside element
      p1pp = parseInt(p1pp) + 1; //Increment
      document.getElementById("p1p").innerHTML = p1pp; // Writing values
    }
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested and it worked for addition but when I now want to remove a point, I get a "Nan" box appearing. Forgive me for my

Comment: @JustinMoon-exe NaN means `Not a Number`. Are you sure that `innerText` contain only numbers and not other characters?